# Generic Class Inheritence and LINQ Extension Methods

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

Let's say I have a generic class looking something like this

```cs
public class GenericCollection<T> : Collection<T>, IQueryable<T>
{
    public string SomeCollectionProperty { get; set; }

    ...
    // IQueryable implentations
}
```

now I have a child classes of the above parent class

```cs
public class SomeCollection : GenericCollection<SomeType>
{
    // Some Additional Functionality here
}
```

Within the generic class I have the full use of the LINQ Extension methods (ex Where, First, Select etc)

As soon as I try to access the LINQ Extension methods in my derived class it seems to forget that it is IQueryable or IEnumerable

I would expect it to do something like this (inside SomeCollection)

```cs
public SomeType FindFirst(int SomeProperty)
{
    return this.First(t => t.someproperty == SomeProperty);
}
```

but instead when I hit the . after this visual studio doesn't give me any of the extension methods

I'm wracking my brain trying to understand why

Especially since if In my Generic class I  just inherit from `Collection<T>` which implements `IEnumerable<T>` which has LINQ Extension methods associated with it I can still use the LINQ Extension methods in my generic class but as soon as I define a strongly typed class based on my generic class I loose the LINQ Extension methods

I hope I didn't just confuse everyone because I sure feel like I'm confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is it can't find the extension methods because you probably need to have:

```
using System.Linq;
```

This should be in your subclass.

Comment: *sigh* of course I would miss the OBVIOUS

That's what I get for thinking all my classes had the same set of using declarations

Thanks for the idiot check :-)

Comment: @Tofu, it happens to us all. :)